# Fisher-KPP equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can you help me understand how to derive the [Fisher-KPP equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_equation)? I.e., how can I figure out where it comes from?

It is easy to find the derivations of the diffusion equation and the heat equation, but I can't find any summary of the way to derive this one...

Will you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [Fisher's own 1937 paper](http://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/15125/1/152.pdf) linked to at the Wikipedia article you provided?

Comment: [physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com) is more suitable for this question as it only relates the knowledge of physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving you a rather more intuitive argument here: for equation
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=r u(1-u)+\color{blue}{\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}},\tag{1}$$ 
if we ignore the blue term, it is just:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=ru(1-u),\tag{2}
$$
which is a Logistic equation. Above pure Logistic equation models the change of a population having growth rate $r$. With blue term added, it means a *diffusion* is added spacially, which can be interpreted as: a bump somewhere in the quantity $u$ will propagate in space, in this case, in a nonlinear way like Burgers' equation.

The equilibria and their stability of (1) inherit the ones in (2), which are $u\equiv 1$ (stable) and $u\equiv 0$ (unstable). The traveling wave solution physically describes an traveling wavefront from the region near the stable solution $u=1$ to the region near unstable solution $u=0$.

Also judging by the first few pages of the paper [*A study of the diffusion equation with increase in the amount of substance, and its application to a biological problem*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-011-3030-1_38) by Kolmogorov-Petrovskii-Piscounov (my library doesn't have this article), the notation is more user-friendly and you might wanna check that out.